# Class template, invalid null pointer(string)

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, null

Created a template class that complies and runs fine with integers, when i attempt to run with strings I receive invalid null pointer error.

I only added in the methods where the heap is created, which is where the error was found.

```
//heap.h
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<class TYPE>
class Heap{
private:

    vector<TYPE> heap;
    int size;// number of elements in the heap
    bool maxheap = true;//default value
    TYPE bubble_up(TYPE item);
    TYPE bubble_down(TYPE item);

public:

    Heap();
    Heap(bool maxheap);
    Heap(vector<TYPE>, bool order);
    ~Heap();
    void build_heap();
    TYPE Insert(TYPE item);
    TYPE Delete(TYPE& item);
    const vector<TYPE> sort(bool order);
    const vector<TYPE> sort();// defualt sort if no variable given, max sort
    TYPE get_size();
    void print_heap();
    void clear_heap();
};

template<class TYPE>
Heap<TYPE>::Heap(){
    TYPE dummy = 0;
    heap.push_back(dummy);
    size = heap.size() - 1;
}

template<class TYPE>
Heap<TYPE>::Heap(bool order){
    maxheap = order; // true is max, false is min
    TYPE dummy = 0;
    heap.push_back(dummy);
    size = heap.size() - 1;

}

template<class TYPE>
Heap<TYPE>::Heap(vector<TYPE> x, bool order){
    maxheap = order;// true is max, false is min
    TYPE tempSize;
    TYPE dummy = 0;
    heap.push_back(dummy);
    size = heap.size() - 1;
    tempSize = x.size();
    for (TYPE y = 0; y < tempSize; y++){
        heap.push_back(x[y]);
    }
    size = heap.size() - 1;
    build_heap();
}
```

I have cut out the part where the issue was found in the next few lines of code.

```
//driver.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Heap.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

typedef string TYPE;

int main(void) {

    Heap<std::string> *s_heap = new Heap<std::string>();  // string heap
    std::string s_item = "0";
}
```

"Debug assertion failed!"
"Expression: Invalid null pointer"

Comment: `TYPE dummy = 0;` is no good if TYPE is a std::string - make it `TYPE dummy` (still questionable, but better)

Comment: @DieterLücking `TYPE dummy{};` or `TYPE dummy = TYPE();`.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Better the first one, who knows whether `TYPE` is moveconstructible / copyconstructible. (even though RVO applies)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<class TYPE>
Heap<TYPE>::Heap(){
    TYPE dummy = 0;
    heap.push_back(dummy);
    size = heap.size() - 1;
}
```

The first line would translate to:

```
 std:string dummy = 0;
```

I don't think you can set a string to zero.

try changing it to:

```
TYPE dummy = TYPE();
```

UPDATE:
as juanchopanza points out, the modern syntax is:

```
TYPE dummy{};
```

(I'm still living in the past...)

Comment: Correct. "setting" a string to zero invokes the `const char*` constructor, which assumes a pointer to a null-terminaded string.

Comment: Another quick question, changing that in the code allowed it to create the heap as a string. Now I get several errors saying "No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous", do I need to make more constructor classes for the string cases? I thought that was the whole idea behind a template

Comment: Where are you getting those errors?  (post it as a new question)